# Select distinct record from mapping table with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

In my MySQL database I have these tables:

[image]

I want to select count of users who only own birds and **no other** pet.

So far I've came up with this:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) FROM users_pets_map WHERE pet_id IN (SELECT id FROM pets WHERE animal = 'bird')`

but it doesn't satisfy the requirement of not owning other animals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your query as below:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) FROM users_pets_map WHERE pet_id IN (SELECT id 

FROM pets WHERE animal = 'bird') AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM 

users_pets_map WHERE pet_id IN (SELECT id FROM pets WHERE animal <> 'bird'))
```

The last sub-query will fetch the pet_id who are not birds, the query outside it will fetch users who have animal other than birds. Finally combined your current query it will fetch you the users who does not have any other animals as well as have bird. Although the above query is not the best possible solution in terms of time complexity, but it's one of many solutions as well as easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can do aggregation :

```
select m.user_id, count(*) 
from user_pets_map m inner join
     pets p
     on p.id = m.pet_id
group by m.user_id 
having sum( p.animal <> 'bird' ) = 0;
```

In other way, you can also do :

```
select m.user_id, count(*) 
from user_pets_map m inner join
     pets p
     on p.id = m.pet_id
group by m.user_id 
having min(p.animal) = max(p.animal) and min(p.animal) = 'bird';
```

**EDIT :** If you want only `User`s count then you can do :

```
select count(distinct m.user_id)
from user_pets_map m
where not exists (select 1 from user_pets_map m1 where m1.user_id = m.user_id and m1.pet_id <> 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` AND `HAVING`

```
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) FROM users_pets_map 
   WHERE pet_id IN (SELECT id FROM pets WHERE animal = 'bird')
    GROUP BY pet_id HAVING COUNT(distinct pet_id)=1
```